# LWJGL - Switching from 3D to 2D to render text with NO external librarys

Tags: java, text, fonts, 3d, lwjgl

I want to render 2D quads on my screen by switching to a 2D scene then switching back to 3D.
I dont want to use any external librarys besides LWJGL.

This is what I got so far:

```
private static void renderLetter(char c, float x, float y) {
    int character = c+1;
    GL11.glPushMatrix();

    setOrthoOn();

    GL11.glTranslatef(x, y, 0);

    float[] xy = game.getResourceManager().getSpriteSheets().get(fontSheet).getXYForCell(character);
    float cellx = game.getResourceManager().getSpriteSheets().get(fontSheet).getCell_sizeX();
    float celly = game.getResourceManager().getSpriteSheets().get(fontSheet).getCell_sizeY();
    float xx = xy[0];
    float yy = xy[1];

    GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, game.getResourceManager().getTextures().get(game.getResourceManager().getSpriteSheets().get(fontSheet).getTextureID()));
    GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(xx, yy);
        GL11.glVertex2f(0,0);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(xx+cellx, yy);
        GL11.glVertex2f(fontSize,0);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(xx+cellx, yy+celly);
        GL11.glVertex2f(fontSize,fontSize);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(xx, yy+celly);
        GL11.glVertex2f(0,fontSize);
    GL11.glEnd();
    GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);      

    setOrthoOff();

    GL11.glPopMatrix();
}

public static void setOrthoOn()
{
    GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_LIGHTING);
    GL11.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);                
    GL11.glClearDepth(1);
    GL11.glViewport(0,0,1360,768);
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
    GL11.glLoadIdentity();
    GL11.glOrtho(0, 1360, 768, 0, 1, -1);
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
    GL11.glLoadIdentity();
}

public static void setOrthoOff()
{
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
    GL11.glLoadIdentity();
    GLU.gluPerspective(game.getFieldOfView(), 1360f/768f, 0.1f, 1000);
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
    GL11.glLoadIdentity();
    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    GL11.glDepthFunc(GL11.GL_LEQUAL);
    GL11.glHint(GL11.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL11.GL_NICEST);
}
```

the first method is to render a letter. what I am trying to do is by calling setOrthoOn switch to 2D rendering then render the quad then call setOrthoOff to switch back to 3D.

This code does nothing for me when I run it.. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This should do it.](http://pastebin.com/DAAYMPNW)

Note: some of the code may be extraneous. I'm not very experienced with OpenGL, but this worked for me. I would also recommend you import GL11 staticly. That way you don't have to type "GL11.BlaBlaBla", you can just type "BlaBlaBla".

Comment: It does not work.. I have switched the inside of my methods to what you gave me and it doesnt work.. I tried not binding a texture and just giving the quad a color to see if it at least renders the quad but it doesnt...

Comment: You may need to add `glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);` to the beginning of that. Also if your window size is not 800x600, change the 800s and 600s in the code to what ever your window size is.

Comment: I dont use lighting currently and I did change it.. its really strange because it doesnt draw the quads... I updated the code..

Comment: Try disabling textures `glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);`

Comment: When? when switching to 2d?

Comment: Nope.. All I see on my screen is my white textureless 3D cube.. No 2D quads

Comment: I have no clue then. My code worked for me so it must be something that you did differently earlier in the program, but I wouldn't know what to tell you.

Comment: And if you're looking to program games, I would recommend starting from scratch with the [Java binding of OpenGL](https://jogamp.org/deployment/archive/rc/gluegen_3-jogl_2/). Just scroll down until you find "jogl-2.0.........zip" and download the one for your operating system. I found it much easier to build an engine from the ground up then to use a pre-built one. That's just me though.